# Not fully scrolls down when a new message arrives

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, frontend

I'm trying to scroll down whenever a new message arrives with the following code:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('chat-body');
    elem!.scrollTop = elem!.scrollHeight;
```

I thought that the reason could be that it might be hiding behind the form, but the scrollbar still had some space to go further down. And if I scroll down manually, it displays the full message.

Comment: try putting these two statements in setTimeout?

Comment: please approve my answer if it helped.

Comment: Sure! Edit it a bit the answer to include the secs (I know it's a small detail but may make a difference for a beginner like me :))

Comment: Btw I can't upvote yet, I don't have enough points to do that :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting these two statements in setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  var elem = document.getElementById('chat-body');
  elem!.scrollTop = elem!.scrollHeight;
}, 100)
```